# A question in number theory...doubt clarification...!!!

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am very new to Number Theory. Got the following thing in notes which I am unable to do:

$P$ is a set with elements $P=\{u_0,u_1,\ldots,u_{n-1}\}$. It was given that for different values of $n\geq 8$  and positive integers $m$ and $p$, the range of $2m$ and $2p+1$ is given as:

For $n\equiv0,1,2, or ~3(mod 4)$ the range of $2m$ and $2p+1$ are respectively

$4<2m\leq n/2$ and $4<2p+1\leq (n/2)-1$;

$4<2m\leq \lfloor n/2\rfloor$ and $4<2p+1\leq \lfloor n/2\rfloor$;

$4<2m\leq (n/2)-1$ and $4<2p+1\leq (n/2)$;

$4<2m\leq \lfloor n/2\rfloor$ and $4<2p+1\leq \lfloor n/2\rfloor$.

Can anybody explain what it really means here? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Which part do you not get?

Comment: the part where range of 2m and 2p+1 is mentioned...I mean what values do they satisfy?

Comment: What context is this from? All this is doing is first taking the remainder of dividing $n$ by 4, giving either 0,1,2 or 3. Then some inequalities are shown. Are these definitions of $m$ and $p$ or are they defined elsewhere? If not then just take the remainder (0,1,2, or 3) and plug it in for $n$ in each of the ranges (note that $\lfloor n \rfloor$ is the largest integer less than $n$)

Comment: The values m and p can take are entirely dependant on the choice of n

Comment: sir, suppose I take n=8 then the range of $2m$ and $2p+1$ are 

$4<2m\leq n/2$ and $4<2p+1\leq (n/2)-1$ i.e.


$4<2m\leq 4$ and $4<2p+1\leq 3$. Am I right?

but then we are not getting any idea. its totally absurd